# Active Directory User failed to login with Error: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure-active-directory, sssd

I'm trying to domain join my AWS redhat linux machine to Azure AD. I've made all the required configuration following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-rhel-linux-vm) document.

Error Message

```
sshd[18242]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.101.xx.xx user=user@SAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM
sshd[18242]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user user@SAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM: 6 (Permission denied)
sshd[18213]: error: PAM: User account has expired for user@SAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM from 10.101.xx.xx
```

My ec2 windows machine was successfully domain joined and I'm able to login using my username.

Can someone please help me what configuration I might be missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you [granted the 'AAD DC Administrators' group sudo privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-rhel-linux-vm#grant-the-aad-dc-administrators-group-sudo-privileges) on the RHEL VM, please make sure you use any of member account that is part 'AAD DC Administrators' group for join domain.